# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 (libGDX)

Tags: android, libgdx

I get Fatal signal 11 on my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge when I try to enter the playscreen. On the desktop emulator it works fine and I can enter the playscreen class. I also tested with a Nexus 6 and it worked even there. What's wrong with my phone?

When I try to debug the app crashes when I'm reading this line:

```
app.getApplicationListener().render();
```

PlayScreen class:

```
public class PlayScreen2 implements Screen {
    private TextureAtlas atlas;


    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    private Hud2 hud;

    private TmxMapLoader maploader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    private World world;
    public Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    public static Runner player;
    private float dt;
    private boolean keyPressed = false;
    private boolean keyPressed2 = false;






    public PlayScreen2(){



        atlas = new TextureAtlas("Runner_And_Enemies.pack");

        gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(RunningGame.V_WIDTH / RunningGame.PPM, RunningGame.V_HEIGHT / RunningGame.PPM, gamecam);
        hud = new Hud2(Globals.game.batch);


        maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = maploader.load("level2.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / RunningGame.PPM);
        gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2 , 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        new B2WorldCreator(world, map);
        player = new Runner(world, this);




    }

    public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){
        return atlas;

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }


    public void handleInput(float dt){

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY)) {
            if (!keyPressed) {
                keyPressed = true;
                if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 4) {
                    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

                }
                Hud2.addscore(1);
            }
        } else {
            keyPressed = false;
        }



        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
            if (!keyPressed2) {
                keyPressed2 = true;
                if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 4.0f) {
                    player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 3.0f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);

                }

            }
        } else {
            keyPressed2 = false;
        }



        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2)
            player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-5.2f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);



    }

    public void update(float dt){
        handleInput(dt);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);



        player.update(dt);
        hud.update(dt);
        gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;

        gamecam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);

        Globals.game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
        Globals.game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(Globals.game.batch);
        Globals.game.batch.end();

        Globals.game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();



    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);



    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();

    }

}
```

Comment: Put tracepoint into your render method of PlayScreen2 and see what happens. You also should see stack trace on logcat

Comment: How do I put the tracepoint in? How should it look like?

Comment: Before debugging, you should a stack trace for this crash on your phone. Just open a console and write "adb logcat" while your device is plugged in your computer. You should see many logs on the screen. Then you will try to start your application, after it has closed press Ctrl + C and stop your trace. Then you should see the reason of crash with the information you gave above "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 (libGDX)". So, you should see and information include "PlayScreen2.java". Please post it here and we can help you